# Having trouble linking to a static library with GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, opengl, glfw

I'm working on a big project with `glfw` but I have been stymied trying to link to a static library with gcc, hence this toy example. I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble with such a simple thing.

This is the extent of my source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H 

int main(){
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
    {
        printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library\n");
    }

    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "fonts/arial.ttf", 0, &face))
    {
        printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running Linux Mint. I downloaded the FreeType library and built it using CMake and my version of GCC. The `libfretype.a` file is in a subdirectory called `junk`. The headers are in a subdirectory called `include`.

We compile it with the following:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -v -Iinclude -Ljunk vex.c -lfreetype -o vex
```

and I get a ton of errors like `sfnt.c:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to 'png_get_error_ptr'` .

Thanks in advance for telling me the silly mistake I made.

Comment: Should `libraries` be as well an include path on gcc?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. The headers are in fact in a folder called `include`. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that the implementation of the function `png_get_error_ptr` is missing. So, the compiler could not generate an executable because some code is missing.

The function `png_get_error_ptr` is implemented in a library named `libpng`. Sometimes, some libraries have some dependencies on another project, in the general case, you need to include all the dependencies to your build to resolve the `linker errors`.

You need to include these libraries in the linker:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -v -Iinclude -Ljunk vex.c -lfreetype -lpng -lz -o vex 
                                                           ^     ^
```

`-lz` is to link against `zlib` because `libpng` rely on `zlib` if I remember correctly.

http://libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt

Comment: Follow up question: I'm trying to write portable code that will "just work" when run on someone else's machine. Will these dependencies be a problem for that?

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as portable code that will "just work". There is something close to this for UNIX-based systems named `autotools`. It's a little bit painful to setup at the first time, but the result is a beautiful tar.gz archive with a configure script. For the user, he just have to extract and type `./configure && make && make install`. If the library is missing, an error message "library libpng is missing" will be displayed. This `autotools` is very nice. Unfortunately, i am not aware of a cross-platform solution which take care of dependencies for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Let me rephrase a little bit; are there best practices I can follow that will give my users the best experience? Autotools is interesting but might be out of scope. And thank you for being so on top of it!

Comment: For users. On Unix-based systems, the most convenient is to provide a source-based tar.gz archive generated by `autotools`. This is the most convenient for most of users. If the project is interesting, it will make easy to integrate to any Linux distribution. For Windows users, the best is to provide executable files, either an installer, either an archive containing the executable and all the DLLs.